# How to provide possible solutions to your own questions?

Tags: discussion, self-answer

You ask a question and you have a few ideas on how to solve it, but you are not sure which, if any, is the best.

Here is a least of possible ways to present these ideas:

1. The first way is to list all the answers you think of in the body of your question. This question is an example of such method.
2. Another method would be to create an answer for each possible solution. I am not sure how this would pan out. Ideally the correct answer would have to address issues with all possible answers and provide insight into the consequences of the solutions before deciding which is the best.

Comment: It sounds like your question is simply not a good fit for SO. *"best"* how, exactly? Why not implement both and test for whatever criteria you have?

Comment: If you already have [multiple] working solutions, it appears that you don't actually have a programming problem to solve anymore; you've already solved it.

Comment: You are correct, this question was intended for sister sites where such questions are acceptable.

Comment: @TomasZubiri then you should ask on those respective site's metas.  The SO community as a whole can't really speak to the policies and best practices for a different site.  There is not likely to be a single practice that is acceptable to the various sites you are speaking about

Comment: Side note: to my knowledge there is no sites in SE network that will accept "the best" as clear requirement.

Comment: If you have an entire coded solution and want feedback, that is where CodeReview comes in.

Answer (score 4):

> The first way is to list all the answers you think of in the body of
>   your question.

This is [explicitly off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask):

> **To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where …**
>
> - your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers: “I use ______ for ______, what do you use?”

Note that this is the **default text** for the Don't Ask page. There may be SE sites that have customized this so that this type of question is OK, but most are going to consider this off topic.

> Another method would be to create an answer for each possible
>   solution.

This wouldn't work either:

1. Writing good self-answered Q&A is hard.
2. If you write a question asking for the "best", it's going to get closed as opinion based.
3. Assuming your question has objective criteria and all of your answers answer the question, then there's no guarantee that the "best" solution is going to get the most up-votes. They could all end up with the same score because they're all correct.

Self-answered Q&A is really meant to be used to share *well-researched knowledge, not just "I tried this and it worked, don't know why"*. – Gimby

Comment: Perhaps its prudent to stress that it is meant to share well-researched knowledge, not just "I tried this and it worked, don't know why".

Comment: @Gimby Agreed. Updated my answer.